# New Gmail email to a WordPress new post?

Tags: posts, email, automation

I have seen several paid, free, trail, etc services ([Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/gmail/wordpress/27326/gmail-new-email-to-wordpress-create-post/), [IFTTT](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/automate-wordpress-ifttt/)) where you can give your gmail email login info and WordPress setup info and it will automate certain processes. For example, once you receive a new email on Gmail, convert that email into a WordPress post. But the only thing that I am worried about with that is:

1. It is not fully free.
2. It is not hosted on my own server and I have no control over it.

Does any knows of a free service, script, program, or module that can be hosted on Linux server that will login into my gmail (or any email?) and will grab new emails (can there be a filter?) and make them into new WordPress posts?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has built-in support for posting via email. Go to Settings > Writing in your admin and enter your credentials under "Post via e-mail".

Note it won't handle Gmail labels (it only works via POP3).